# How can I get unbound start up with system

Tags: 14.04

I installed the latest unbound in Ubuntu 14.04 from Ubuntu main server and do some configuration in unbound.conf. Then , reboot the system. I found unbound didn't work at all after system on. But When I start it with command "sudo invoke-rc.d unbound start", I found unbound started up successfully.

I checked /var/log/syslog and found some error occured while unbound-anchor updated the root key file during unbound started up with system. The error like this:

```
unbound-anchor: /var/lib/unbound/root.key has content
unbound-anchor: fail: the anchor is NOT ok and could not be fixed
```

I checked `/etc/init.c/unbound` and found the scrpit to update the root key. Like this

```
if $ROOT_TRUST_ANCHOR_UPDATE; then
                unbound-anchor -a $ROOT_TRUST_ANCHOR_FILE -v 2>&1 | logger -p daemon.info -t unbound-anchor
                chown unbound:unbound $ROOT_TRUST_ANCHOR_FILE
fi
```

I run "`sudo unbound-anchor -a /var/lib/unbound/root.key -v 2>&1 | logger -p daemon.info -t unbound-anchor`", and found it worked well.

I guess it's about something like lack of authority while unbound-anchor execute. I have no idea about how to fix it. This is my configuration in unbound.conf. I checked it with unbound-checkconf command and no error found.

```
include: "/etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/*.conf"
server:
    verbosity: 5
    use-syslog: no
    logfile: "/var/lib/unbound/unbound.log"
    log-time-ascii: yes
    log-queries: no
    val-log-level: 0
    statistics-interval: 600
    statistics-cumulative: yes
    extended-statistics: yes
    pidfile: "/var/lib/unbound/unbound.pid"

    interface: 192.168.1.101@53
    access-control: 192.168.1.0/24 allow
    port: 53
    outgoing-interface: 192.168.1.101
    #outgoing-range: 2048
    num-queries-per-thread: 1024
    do-daemonize: yes
    do-tcp: yes
    do-udp: yes
    tcp-upstream: yes
    do-ip4: yes
    do-ip6: no
    #root-hints: "/etc/unbound/named.cache" 
    #dlv-anchor-file: "/var/lib/unbound/dlv.isc.org.key"
    cache-min-ttl: 300
    cache-max-ttl: 86400
    infra-host-ttl: 900
    val-bogus-ttl: 900
    so-reuseport: no
    num-threads: 10
    prefetch: yes
    prefetch-key: yes
    #ssl-upstream: no
    #val-permissive-mode: yes
    do-not-query-localhost: yes
    neg-cache-size: 0k
forward-zone:
    name: "."
    forward-addr: 202.60.252.9
    forward-addr: 202.76.4.18
    forward-addr: 202.177.2.2
    forward-addr: 202.60.252.8
    forward-addr: 202.181.224.2
    forward-addr: 202.180.160.1
    forward-addr: 8.8.8.8
    forward-addr: 8.8.4.4
    forward-first: yes
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and figured out the network interface had to be properly initialized before running unbound. So I now start unbound in a post-up script.